# RAM crashed for XML to DataFrame conversion function

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have created the following function which converts an XML File to a DataFrame. This function works good for files smaller than 1 GB, for anything greater than that the RAM(13GB Google Colab RAM) crashes. Same happens if I try it locally on Jupyter Notebook (4GB Laptop RAM). Is there a way to optimize the code?

**Code**

```
#Libraries
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

#Function to convert XML file to Pandas Dataframe    
def xml2df(file_path):

  #Parsing XML File and obtaining root
  tree = ET.parse(file_path)
  root = tree.getroot()

  dict_list = []

  for _, elem in ET.iterparse(file_path, events=("end",)):
      if elem.tag == "row":
        dict_list.append(elem.attrib)      # PARSE ALL ATTRIBUTES
        elem.clear()

  df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
  return df
```

**Part of an XML File ('Badges.xml')**

```
<badges>
  <row Id="82946" UserId="3718" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82947" UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82949" UserId="3893" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82950" UserId="4591" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82951" UserId="5196" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82952" UserId="2635" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82953" UserId="1113" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
```

I also tried the `SAX` code but I get the same RAM Exhausted error.
import xml.sax

```
import xml.sax    

class BadgeHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = None
        self.row_data = []
        self.df = None

    # Call when an element starts
    def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
        if tag == 'row':
            self.row = attributes._attrs

    # Call when an elements ends
    def endElement(self, tag):
        if self.row and tag == 'row':
            self.row_data.append(self.row)

    def endDocument(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.row_data)

LOAD_FROM_FILE = True

handler = BadgeHandler()
if LOAD_FROM_FILE:
    print('loading from file')
    # 'rows.xml' is a file that contains your XML example
    xml.sax.parse('/content/Badges.xml', handler)
else:
    print('loading from string')
    xml.sax.parseString(xml_str, handler)
print(handler.df)
```

Comment: Does it crash if you remove the attempt to create the dataframe out of the `dict_list`?

Comment: Also, please show the actual traceback/error you're getting.

Comment: @AKX I don't get a traceback, the RAM just crashes and the session restarts. I did not have any other way of creating the dataframe other than `dict_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. there is a way to optimize the code.

Use [SAX](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.reader.html).

With SAX you will not load the entire XML into RAM.

See here for an example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm

Code below:

```
import xml.sax

import pandas as pd

xml_str = '''<badges>
  <row Id="82946" UserId="3718" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.923" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82947" UserId="994" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82949" UserId="3893" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82950" UserId="4591" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82951" UserId="5196" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82952" UserId="2635" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="82953" UserId="1113" Name="Teacher" Date="2008-09-15T08:55:03.957" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  </badges>'''


class BadgeHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = None
        self.row_data = []
        self.df = None

    # Call when an element starts
    def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
        if tag == 'row':
            self.row = attributes._attrs

    # Call when an elements ends
    def endElement(self, tag):
        if self.row and tag == 'row':
            self.row_data.append(self.row)

    def endDocument(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.row_data)


LOAD_FROM_FILE = True

handler = BadgeHandler()
if LOAD_FROM_FILE:
    print('loading from file')
    # 'rows.xml' is a file that contains your XML example
    xml.sax.parse('rows.xml', handler)
else:
    print('loading from string')
    xml.sax.parseString(xml_str, handler)
print(handler.df)
```

output

```
      Id UserId     Name                     Date Class TagBased
0  82946   3718  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.923     3    False
1  82947    994  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
2  82949   3893  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
3  82950   4591  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
4  82951   5196  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
5  82952   2635  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
6  82953   1113  Teacher  2008-09-15T08:55:03.957     3    False
```

Comment: OP is using iterparse. It doesn't load the file into RAM either.

Comment: @AKX see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse "Parses an XML section into an element tree incrementally..."

Comment: Ah, you're correct, it looks like. LXML's `iterparse` doesn't yield the eventual tree :)

Comment: @balderman I looked into SAX but I am not able to write the code for the same, I am quite new to working with XML files. Can you provide the code?

Comment: @IshanDutta provide a small snippet of the XML (make sure the XML is valid)

Comment: @balderman I have added part of the xml file. The other xml files which I want to convert to a dataframe have almost the same structure.

Comment: @IshanDutta Code was added to the my answer

Comment: @balderman when I execute the code with the file name `xml_str = '/content/Badges.xml'`, I get the following error `SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Comment: It makes sense.. a file is not a string. Try to find the API that sax use in order to load a file. Post a comment if you fail

Comment: The code was updated and it support loading the xml from a string or from a file

Comment: @balderman unfortunately the code crashed even with the updated code.

Comment: `Error: Your session crashed after using all available RAM`

Comment: As you can understand your computer RAM is limited. Add a row counter to the code and see how many rows you were able to handle. What is the total number of rows? You may consider using tools like spark.

Comment: The total number of rows is more than 500K. Can you suggest another alternative as what can be done?

Comment: If the data is too big you should use a framework that will split the work between few computers. Another option is to load subset of the data. What happens if you use a file with 300k records only?

Comment: The smaller files that I have are less than 100K, the code works for them. The rest of the files have more than 500K rows.

Comment: See https://spark.apache.org/ it will solve the issue. You are dealing with big data so you need to use big data tools

Comment: @balderman See my new answer :) Turns out it's an inefficiency in Pandas in this use case.

Answer (score 1):

You're both loading the file into memory *and* iterating over it.

Switch to [`lxml`'s `iterparse`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#event-driven-parsing):

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree


def xml2df(file_path):
    dict_list = []
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        for _, elem in etree.iterparse(f, events=("end",)):
            if elem.tag == "row":
                dict_list.append(elem.attrib)
                #elem.clear()

    return pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
```

Comment: @IshanDutta Edited, try again. You'll need to install lxml.

Comment: I get traceback `'lxml' has no attribute 'iterparse'`

Comment: Oops, my bad. it's `lxml.etree.iterparse`. Fixed.

Comment: I tried `lxml.etree.iterparse`, the output has only the `index` and no columns other than that.

Comment: If I remove `elem.clear()` then once again the RAM crashes.

Comment: Then you're going to need a SAX-like parser, as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I tried the SAX method but I am still getting the same RAM crash, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Can you add the full code you're running for the SAX stuff in your question?

Comment: I'm requesting the full code you use for a reason, just to be sure you aren't accidentally loading the XML into memory in another step.

Comment: I have added the code, please have a look. The xml file is stored in this location `/content/Badges.xml`

Comment: @IshanDutta Please see my new answer – turns out you'll have to go through a CSV file for more efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to dig deeper into this.

It turns out Pandas is **very inefficient memory-wise** when creating dataframes from a list-of-dicts for who knows why.

[You can find my full experiment code (that generates a gigabyte of XML and reads it) on GitHub](https://github.com/akx/so63265336), but the gist of it is that (on my Python 3.8, macOS)

- reading the XML document to a dataframe with code adapted from @balderman's answer (`read_xml_to_pd.py`):

  - takes 6,838,556k (~7 GB) to 10,508,892k (~10 GB) memory (who knows why it varies) and about 52 seconds to read the data into memory
  - 12,128,400k (12.1 GB) memory to hold that data and the dataframe
- reading the XML document to a CSV file (with SAX):

  - takes 16-17 megabytes of memory and some 1.5 minutes to write a 400-megabyte `badges.csv` (`python read_xml_to_csv.py`)
  - takes up to 2,989,080k (2.9 GB) memory and about 10 seconds to read the CSV using `pd.read_csv()` (`read_csv_to_pd.py`)
  - finally 2,033,208k (2.0 GB) memory is required to just hold the dataframe

A binary intermediate format would probably be faster and more efficient still.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @AKX  The `read_xml_to_csv.py` file is giving the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'start_memory_usage_thread'`. One more thing instead of `util` I had written `utils`.

Comment: The code as is worked fine for me as I committed it. But you don't need the tracking thread for your usage.

Comment: This code worked if I used files of size less than 2 GB, when I used it for larger files the code cell just keeps running forever. The files that are causing problems are of "zipped size" of 4 gb and 15 gb. Any suggestions @AKX ?

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out an alternate way to process the data rather than trying to load it into a single dataframe. (Or use a machine with lots more memory.)

Comment: @AKX should I use Pyspark for working with the data?

Comment: Really depends on what you want to do with it in the end. For many analysis cases, you don't need to have all of the data in memory all the time...

Comment: @AKX This code is a part of a Research Project, so I can't really say for sure what I am going to find at the end. So which will be better to use Pyspark or to parse the xml files for only the required data?

Comment: @AKX can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950652/how-to-fix-index-error-due-to-level-in-pandas-groupby  . I think you may help.