# How to fix Index Error due to level in Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame `badges`. The column `UserId` includes multiple entries for same user. I want to obtain the minimum value of `Date` for every `UserId` for a given `BadgeName`. I have created a function `user_badge_dt` to perform the same but I get Index Error. The point to note is that although the dataset is same for all users, I get this error only for some badges and not for others. I don't know why this is happening.

**Part of Badges DataFrame**

```
    UserId    BadgeName            Date                   
0     23    Curious         2016-01-12T18:44:49.267 
1     22    Autobiographer  2017-01-12T18:44:49.267 
2     23    Curious         2018-01-12T18:44:49.267 
3     20    Autobiographer  2019-01-12T18:44:49.267 
4     22    Autobiographer  2020-01-12T18:44:49.267
5     30    Curious         2020-01-12T18:44:49.267
```

**Function**

```
#Function to obtain UserId with the date-time of obtaining given badge for the first time
def user_badge_dt(badge_name):
  
  #Creating DataFrame to obtain all UserId and date-Time of given badge
  df = badges[['UserId','Date']].loc[badges.Name == badge]
  
  #Obtaining the first date-time of badge attainment
  v = df.groupby("UserId", group_keys=False)['Date'].nsmallest(1)
  v.index = v.index.droplevel(1)

  df['date'] = df['UserId'].map(v)
  df.drop(columns='Date',inplace=True)
  
  #Removing all duplicate values of Users
  df.drop_duplicates(subset='UserId',  inplace=True )

  return df
```

**Error**

```
IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2
```

**Note**
On furthur inspection I found the error was being caused at this line
`v.index = v.index.droplevel(1)`

This was because the previous code line is giving different results for different badge names:

CASE 1: When code works correctly for given badge

> df = badges[['UserId','Date']].loc[badges.Name == 'Autobiographer']
> v = df.groupby("UserId", group_keys=False)['Date'].nsmallest(1)
> print(v)

o/p:

```
    1   22    2017-01-12T18:44:49.267 
    3   20    2019-01-12T18:44:49.267
```

(This output has `index`, `UserId` and minimum value of `Date` for given badge)

CASE 2: When code works incorrectly for given badge

> df = badges[['UserId','Date']].loc[badges.Name == 'Curious']
> v = df.groupby("UserId", group_keys=False)['Date'].nsmallest(1)
> print(v)

o/p:

```
      23   2016-01-12T18:44:49.267 
      30   2020-01-12T18:44:49.267
```

(This output does not have `index` that is why code is failing at the next line. I don't know how is it happening.)

The expected output of the function for any input `badge_name` should return a dataframe with the `UserId` and the minimum value of `Date` the given badge. If my function is unclear, please provide a different way to achieve this using a new function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot simulate your error, but I think your solution should be simplify with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) - then get all first users with smallest dates:

```
badges['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(badges['Date'])

def user_badge_dt(badge_name):
  
  #Creating DataFrame to obtain all UserId and date-Time of given badge
  return  (badges.loc[badges.BadgeName == badge_name, ['UserId','Date']]
                 .sort_values('Date')
                 .drop_duplicates(subset='UserId'))
```